# Who wrote Chaar Hatsioun?

Tags: jewish-books, authorship

Who wrote the book entitled Chaar Hatsioun?

I just know the title of the book. All I know is that it is about the halakha in general.

Answer (score 6):

The Sha'ar Hatziyun is footnotes to his Mishna Berura as written by Rabbi Yisroel Meir Hakohen Kagan, author of the Chafetz Chaim. Other than to reference citations, the purpose of these footnotes is to typically bring short notes of interest that are tangentially related to the core topic.

Comment: In the absence of any further description, the fact that "it is about halakha in general" makes another book with the same title an equally likely candidate: [Sha'ar haTziyon](http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?25591), by R' Hayim Yaakov ben Tzvi (first printed in 1757). Maybe you'd like to add that to your answer?

Comment: @ShimonbM - Maybe separate that out into your own answer. Personally, I very much doubt OP was talking about that.

Comment: @ShimonbM That title is also presumably transliterated as *Sha'ar HaTziyun* - see the subtitle/description (בו יצוינו כל המקומות...).

Comment: @ShimonbM Also, that's essentially a reference book, while the one by the Chafetz Chaim at least sometimes discusses *halacha* and is associated with a *halachic* work.

Comment: @ShimonbM Actually, regarding transliteration, see the footnote on my answer below. Thanks for bringing up that *sefer*.

Answer (score 4):

<sup>To expand on [Yehuda's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/38097):</sup>

You are most likely referring to the *Sha'ar HaTziyun* (שער הציון), which is the name that [Rabbi Yisrael Meir Kagan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_Meir_Kagan) (also known as the Chafetz Chaim, after the [title of his work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chofetz_Chaim) on the laws of forbidden speech)  gave to his footnotes on the [*Mishna B'rura*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mishnah_Berurah) (which is his *halachic* commentary on the [*Orach Chayim*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orach_Chayim) section of the [*Shulchan Aruch*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shulchan_Aruch) and the gloss of the [Rama](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_Isserles) thereon).<sup>1</sup> The following description is from the author's preface to the *Mishna B'rura* (my translation):

> And on the bottom of the page I opened a gate named the Gate of Note (*Sha'ar HaTziyun*)<sup>2</sup> in which I cited everything in the *Mishna B'rura* in order to know from whom these insights originated. Where I saw a difference of opinion among two *acharonim* (later authorities) on a matter, I was not reticent to search the corpus of works of the other *acharonim* to see to whom among the holy ones does their opinion incline practically - and especially in the Explication of the Gr"a of blessed memory (*Bei'ur HaGr"a* - the [Vilna Gaon's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vilna_Gaon) commentary on the *Shulchan Aruch*), who is the light of Israel and the mainstay upon which everything depends and who is fitting to settle the matter. I also searched the books of the *rishonim* (medieval authorities), that I might find a matter explained explicitly or some other clear proof, for Blessed be HaShem that I have many books of the *rishonim*.

Aside from citation of sources, *Sha'ar HaTziyun* occasionally makes brief comments on the opinions of various *halachic authorities*. However, in-depth discussion and analysis of topics mentioned in the *Mishna B'rura* is generally reserved for *Bei'ur Halacha*, another companion commentary for the *Mishna B'rura* that was also authored by the Chafetz Chaim.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>It is less likely that you are referring to a [reference work](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/35313) by Rabbi Chaim Ya'akov Kramer of [Ashmyany](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashmyany) with the same title as above (mentioned in [a comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38088/who-wrote-chaar-hatsioun#comment100861_38097) by [Shimon bM](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1659/shimon-bm); a brief Hebrew biography of R' Kramer can be found [here](http://benyehuda.org/levinson/kraemer.html)). His שער הציון, published in 1877, provides extensive references from the Talmud (Bavli and Y'rushalmi) and commentators for 123 topics and concepts discussed throughout the Talmud. R' Kramer's work received approbations from the [Netziv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naftali_Zvi_Yehuda_Berlin) and Rabbi [Refael Shapiro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refael_Shapiro). R' Kramer was an ardent Zionist, and most of his works included the word ציון (*Tziyon* - Zion) in the title. This title evokes the verse ([*T'hillim* 87:2](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2687.htm#2)): אהב יהוה שערי ציון מכל משכנות יעקב - "The LORD loveth the **gates of Zion** more than all the dwellings of Jacob." However, R' Kramer intended to invest the title with multiple meanings. One meaning refers to the marking/documenting of sources that is the purpose of the book, as indicated by the description on the title page ("בו יצוינו כל המקומות..."; see fn. 2 below). Additionally, the title hints that the book should serve as a [memorial to R' Kramer's father](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35313&st=&pgnum=9) ("ציון לנפש מר אבא"). It is therefore unclear which pronunciation of the title R' Kramer would have preferred.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>The name *Sha'ar HaTziyun* derives from the phrase "sh'arim hamtzuyanim b'halacha" ([*B'rachos* 8a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=8&format=text), אמר רב חסדא... אוהב ה' שערים המצויינים בהלכה יותר מבתי כנסיות ומבתי מדרשות), translated as "gateways distinguished in (or marked in) Jewish Law." (This phrase in the Talmud involves a play on words from the verse in *T'hillim* mentioned in fn. 1 above). The Chafetz Chaim likely chose the title as a pun, hinting at the distinction of scholarship referenced in his work, but primarily referring to the function of Sha'ar HaTziyun in marking sources of *halacha*.</sub>

Comment: Just for the record: Bi'ur = ביעור = destroy, while Bei'ur = ביאור = explicate.

Comment: @DoubleAA True. Thanks for the explication.

Comment: It is said most chidushim are in the shaar hatsiyon not the biur halacha.